# How to convert a Ruby classname ("NewUserBatch") to string with underscores ("new_user_batch")

Tags: ruby, string, class

I need a generic way to convert classnames to lowercase with underscores. For example, I wish to convert the classname `NewUserBatch` to `new_user_batch`. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the simple case, where you only have **non-namespaced** class names, you can use this oneliner:

**EDIT:** updated with positive look-ahead assertion (thanks @vladr)

```
"MYRubyClassName".gsub(/(.)([A-Z](?=[a-z]))/,'\1_\2').downcase

# => "my_ruby_class_name"
```

This finds all uppercase chars that follow another char and in turn is followed by a lower case char, inserts underscore before it and then downcases everything.

Comment: Beware, the regexp above is buggy; for example `"REGGE".gsub(/(.)([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').downcase` ends up being `r_eg_ge`.  @Laas should make use of zero-width look-ahead or look-behind assertions or make it a two-pass the way Rails does it, see @oldergod's reply.

Answer (score 7):

[`Underscore`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-underscore).

```
>> 'NewUserBatch'.underscore
=> "new_user_batch"
```

It is included in Rails so if you don't use it, you can refer to its source code.

```
def underscore(camel_cased_word)
  word = camel_cased_word.to_s.dup
  word.gsub!(%r::/, '/')
  word.gsub!(%r(?:([A-Za-z\d])|^)(#{inflections.acronym_regex})(?=\b|[^a-z])/) { "#{$1}#{$1 && '_'}#{$2.downcase}" }
  word.gsub!(%r([A-Z\d]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2')
  word.gsub!(%r([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2')
  word.tr!("-", "_")
  word.downcase!
  word
end
```

Comment: Great, I was trying `tableize` but there were some issues with that, this seems to work great!

Answer (score 0):

Also a nice tip: to find if you know INPUT (NewUserBatch) and OUTPUT (new_user_batch) use the following method

```
"NewUserBatch".find_method("new_user_batch")
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work from eater the Rails console or irb.